# Bootstrap3 вложенность container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите разобраться с сеткой. 
Внутри container-fluid есть две колонки (col-md-8 и col-md-4). col-md-8 - это background с контентом, а col-md-4 - это image. Как сделать, чтобы background и image тянулись на всю ширину экрана, а контент не прижимался к левому краю?
Спасибо за помощь[image: ![Scrin]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy5ud.jpg)

Comment: немного не понятно, что должно в итоге получиться

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста на скрин из psd и думаю Вы поймёте. Нужно сверстать как в макете. Т.е. картинка и левая часть backgrond выходят за сетку, т.е. как я понимаю этот блок должен находится в container-fluid, правильно?

Comment: Думаю, что вам стоит поиграться (кастомизировать) с компонентом `card`, внутри которого разместить контейнер, а уже в контейнер все остальное. Изображению дать позиционирование и прочее из этой оперы. Это я описал для первого изображения (со столом которое).

Comment: На Bootstrap нельзя построить все на свете. Почти всегда нужно импровизировать, добавляя либо свои компоненты, либо кастомизировать дефолтные - это нормальная практика. Но важно держать себя в руках и не разводить срач.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдёт такое решение.
Мы добавим несколько стилей для .col с картинкой. Зададим позиционирование, что бы выйти за рамки кола и прижмем картинку к правому краю контейнера.

1) Добавьте класс **bicycle** контейнеру с картинкой: class="col-md-4 bicycle".
Вот класс:

```
.bicycle{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

2) Так же убедитесь что для картинки не задана ни width ни max-width. В фотошопе сделайте размер картинки как в макете, она встанет как надо. Если у вас где то глобально прописаны для картинок max-width, просто переопределите её в css вот так:

```
.bicycle img{
  max-width: none;
}
```

**Готово.** Добавлю ещё 3 пункт на случай если возникнут вопросы при уменьшении окна браузера.

3) Когда начнете уменьшать макет и он выйдет за пределы "md" верстка сломается, что бы исправить нужно создать медиазапрос:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .bicycle{
      position: relative;
  }
  .bicycle img{
      max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Это отменит все наши манипуляции и можно дальше работать в обычном режиме, делать наш текст на 12 колонок а картинку опустить ниже или вообще убрать.